# Reset Undo on the tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have one editor where I switch between content in one editor, and what I want to do when I set the new content, I would like to reset the undo possibility.

I have read on this site http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.UndoManager

That it's just to call `tinymce.UndoManager.clear()` but I just get that the function is undefined.

Comment: On the WP default TinyMCE editor is the undo button include, inside the line 2 of the TinyMCE editor. You see this second line only, after click on "Toolbar Toggle" button, the last button on TinyMCE line 1.

Comment: @Fredrik Could you post the code you're working with so we can use that as a starting point to help you? Particularly, where you're running the `clear()` function

Answer (score 1):

The global variable `tinyMCE` has an array of editors. So you have to call the `undoManager` inside them. Like this for default wp editor on post edit/create screen:

```
tinyMCE.editors[0].undoManager.clear();
```

If you want to do it in a specific editor, select the editor id in `n` like this:

```
var n = 0; // editor id
tinyMCE.editors[n].undoManager.clear();
```